# Get Each Element in a List using Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
l = ['abc,def,ghi,jkl']
```

Now I want the result should be in the format `abc, def, ghi,jkl` as a separate element using python.

How do I do that?

I tried doing something else, but I am getting the result as 'a',b','c', etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have constructed your list incorectly, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15380003/1561176). I suspect the reason is simple confusion, but I recommend you finish the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) before you progress too far or get confused too much and give up with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what result you want:

```
>>> l = ['abc,def,ghi,jkl']
>>> l[0]
'abc,def,ghi,jkl'
>>> l[0].split(',')
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
>>> ', '.join(l[0].split(','))
'abc, def, ghi, jkl'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [split function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
res = 'abc,def,ghi,jkl'.split(',')
```

Or:

```
l = ['abc,def,ghi,jkl']
output = []

for row in l:
    output.extend(row.split(','))
# output will contain all the separate items for all items of l if more than one
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner:

```
', '.join([ e for s in l for e in s.split(',') ])

'abc, def, ghi, jkl'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have as your example:

```
l = ['abc,def,ghi,jkl']
```

Is indeed a list, but a list with only one single item in it. This item is `'abc,def,ghi,jkl'` The reason you only have one item in your list is because you created a string by starting with this character: `'` and then everything that comes after that until you close the string with another `'` is still the same string.

If you wanted to have four strings in your list, you should have written:

```
l = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

This gives you a list, here the first item is `'abc'` and then the comma (`,`) tells the list constructor to treat the next object as another item, and so you get `'def'` and so on....

Comment: ya its correct, but i am passing that list into web service and in web service it is automatically converting into str object.

Comment: @Janardhan In that case, your question needs to be amended to explain *exactly* what you are trying to do, because it seems like you are simply struggling with the basic concepts of list construction in Python from your question.